# Que puedo hacer con este problema Uncaught (in promise)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

He estado desarrollando un código con el que estoy aprendiendo `fetch`. Ésta vez cuando estoy ejecutando el código me lanza un error:

> *Uncaught (in promise)* y el nombre que yo le tenga en el reject

Me dice que está en la primera línea del `html`, pero si lo abro me lanza a la línea donde ejecuto el `then`.

He estado averiguando y siempre este error sale con algo más, pero esta vez no.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

[image: Imagen del error en consola]

```js
var divus=document.querySelector("#usuarios");
    var Janet=document.querySelector("#Janet");
    var avatar=document.querySelector("#avatar");
        getUsuarios()
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(users =>{listadousuarios(users.data);

            return getJanet();
            })
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(user => {
                Ujanet(user.data);

            return getInfo();
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            });

                function getUsuarios(){
                    return fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users");
                }

                function getJanet(){
                    return fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/2");
                    console.log(getJanet);
                }

                //nueva promesas
                    function getInfo(){
                        var informacion = {
                            nombre: 'Sebastian',
                            Apellidos: 'Zamora Urrego',
                            web:'http://sebaszaur.web',

                    }

                    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
                            var info_string = JSON.stringify(getInfo);
                            if(typeof info_string != "string")return reject('');

                            return resolve(info_string);
                        })
                    }
                function listadousuarios(usuarios){

                    usuarios.map((user, i) => {
                    let nombre= document.createElement("h3");

                    nombre.innerHTML=i + user.first_name + " " + user.last_name;
                    divus.appendChild(nombre);
                });
                }
                function Ujanet(user){

                    console.log(user);

                    let nombre= document.createElement("h3");
                    nombre.innerHTML=user.first_name + " " + user.last_name;
                    Janet.appendChild(nombre);
                    avatar.appendChild;
                };
```

Comment: Cuando haces `JSON.stringify(getInfo)` no debería de ser `JSON.stringify(informacion)` ?

Comment: tienes muchos errores en el codigo, procura organizarlo mejor, asi podemos ver bien de que se trata y si hay mas errores, yo ya encontre 2 errores y una sugerencia.